# Excel VBA Updating Powerpoint Chart with Data from Another Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, graph, powerpoint

I am trying to update an existing chart in Powerpoint with excel data from a different excel file. First I tried linking and that didn't work so tried embedding data. I am using 365.

As a first step I copied the different data into a new tab (Taxable Graphs Orig tab versus Taxable Graphs Old tab) in the same excel file. Next step would be to copy data directly from different file.

The below code runs but the chart doesn't update.

```
Sub updatechartdatatest()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
Set pppres2 = PPApp.ActivePresentation


Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
Set pppres = PPApp.ActivePresentation

pppres.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart 2").Chart.Select

 With pppres.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart 2")
 .Chart.ChartData.Activate
 '.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets("Taxable Graphs 
   Orig").Range("b4:K8").Copy
 .Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets("Taxable Graphs 
 Old").Range("b4:K8").Copy
 .Chart.Refresh
End With
```

etc ....

Thank you for your help with this!